# What is the meaning of this question asked by the Mandalorian armorer?

Tags: star-wars, the-mandalorian

When the main character in The Mandalorian brings beskar metal to the armorer, she asks him "Has your signet been revealed?"  The Mandalorian replies that it hasn't yet.  She then forges him the shoulder piece.

What does this exchange about revealing the signet mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the Polygon article ["Beskar, signets, and why armor is everything in The Mandalorian"](https://www.polygon.com/2019/11/12/20961054/the-mandalorian-star-wars-beskar-metal-armor-signet-purge-explained):

> Along with the passing reference to Beskar, the Armorer also asks the Mandalorian if his signet has been revealed. He says not yet, so she makes him a plain, pauldron. We don’t know exactly what this might mean; **it seems possible that this refers to a personalized marking that Mandalorians may receive at some point over time, perhaps after a certain number of missions, or at a certain point in their life.**
>
> We know that personalized armor is very important to Mandalorians, so a valued signet would be make sense. In Legends, the Mandalorians would color their armor with either specific missions that were important to them — for instance sand-gold armor represented a quest for vengeance — or simply colors they liked. While this isn’t explicitly canon anymore, Sabine does exactly this in Star Wars: Rebels when she decorates her Mandalorian armor herself.